# Can not access properties of model object with an error saying "Cannot redefine property: name" in a Ember handlebar template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In a ember template, my model.partners is an array of objects and I tried to iterate and print all name properties but I got an error saying `"Cannot redefine property:  name"`

```
{{#each partner in model.partners}}
   <li>
        {{partner.name}}
   </li>
{{/each}}

---> I got an error saying "Cannot redefine property: name"
```

So I tried `{{log partner}}` helper to see if each partner object is correct, it show correct object information including name property.

```
{{#each partner in model.partners}}
   <li>
        {{log partner}}
   </li>
{{/each}}

----> This iteration print all information of model.partners correctly
```

Here is my Ember environment information.

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.0.3 
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 


Ember Inspector ($E): Object {userInfo: Object, partners: (...),__ember1395345243022_meta: Meta}
```

What could be an issue here? 
Any help will be much appreciated.

**-Edit**

I am just wondering what the error message means "Can not redefine propery:" and who is complaining this.

This is the log from the Ember Inspector when I got the error using {{partner.name}}, you can see Ember.watchKey is the top of the stack

```
Transitioned into 'landing'                        libs.js:6215
Transition #0: TRANSITION COMPLETE.                libs.js:6215

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: name libs.js:6595
Ember.watchKey                                     libs.js:6595
Ember.watch                                        libs.js:7114
Ember.addObserver                                  libs.js:8386
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.registerObserver  libs.js:27048
simpleBind                                         libs.js:30930
bindHelper                                         libs.js:31030
(anonymous function)                               libs.js:30978
program1                                           templates.js:130
prog                                               libs.js:475
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.render            libs.js:26009
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend._renderToBuffer libs.js:24947
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._renderToBuffer   libs.js:26578
superWrapper
```

The following log is the one I got when I was successful to see partner objects through console using {{log partner}}, you can see 7 partner objects in the Ember Inspector. Please understand blurring out actual names for privacy reason.

```
Transitioned into 'landing'                       libs.js:6215
Transition #0: TRANSITION COMPLETE.               libs.js:6215

Object {value: 0, name: "ASM", idx: 0}            libs.js:6215
Object {value: 1, name: "Air Force", idx: 1}      libs.js:6215
Object {value: 2, name: "Army", idx: 2}           libs.js:6215
Object {value: 3, name: "Coast Guard", idx: 3}    libs.js:6215
Object {value: 4, name: "Marines", idx: 4}        libs.js:6215
Object {value: 5, name: "Navy", idx: 5}           libs.js:6215
Object {value: 6, name: "Wives", idx: 6}          libs.js:6215
```

Would you guide me how/where to start debugging this issue? I have a plenty of time for this and let me know any help you need from me.
Thanks.

Comment: I *think* (not sure) that `name` may be a protected variable name.  Try changing it to `partnerName` and see if it's any different.

Comment: I also try {{model.userInfo.uuID}} but still getting "Cannot redefine property: uuID".  When I try {{log model.userInfo.uuID}}, I can see a correct value through the console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the loop like this?

```
{{#each model.partners}}
   <li>
        {{name}}
   </li>
{{/each}}
```

In side the each block the `this` is the model in the array that is being looped over. so oyu could write it `{{this.name}}` but the this is inplied so it can be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply in advance.
Unfortunately, Both {{name}} and {{this.name}} using {{#each model.partners}} are not working. I mean I am still getting "Cannot redefine property: name" error. I am wondering who is complaining with this error.

Comment: To me it looks like you have a model that has many `partners` of this this the partner model? If this is the partner model then you can do this `{{#each}}{{name}}{{/each}}` if you want me to explain this pattern let me know.

Comment: Let me explain the model object that I am using. I can see the following model info through Ember Inspector.  Ember Inspector ($E):  

Object {userInfo: Object, partners: (...),  __ember1395345243022_meta: Meta} As you can see here,  the partners property of this model holds many partner objects. I am really stuck here.

Comment: Can you add a copy of your models for user and partners. I would like to know how you are setting up the relationships between the models.

Comment: FYI, I didn't define a model by using "DS.Model.extend" for this Landing router, rather I set up the model in 'Landing' router using 'setupController' hook to make it available in the landing template.

Here is a copy of the model.

{"userInfo":{"uid":0,"username":"","isRegistered":0,"email":""}, "partners":[{"value":0,"name":"ASM","idx":0},{"value":1,"name":"Air Force","idx":1},{"value":2,"name":"Army","idx":2},{"value":3,"name":"Coast Guard","idx":3}]}

As you can see, there are no relationships in the model object.

Please feel free to let me know if you need more information.
Thanks much.

Comment: Quick fix, I meant route by router in above comment. I was confused. sorry about that.

Comment: Can you make jsbin with this data

Comment: I am afraid of saying this. My project includes other libraries and  is being compiled / concatenated into big several files(app.js, libs.js, etc ...) as you can imagine, so it's too big to make a jsbin. 
Also I added more debugging information in edit section above for you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this issue.

I used the following codes in the model hook when I got the error.

```
model: function() { 
    return new  Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
                 ... 
                 // JSON data from the server
                 //{"userInfo":{"uid":0,"username":"","isRegistered":0,"email":""}, "partners":[{"value":0,"name":"ASM","idx":0},{"value":1,"name":....}...]} 

                 var retObj = {'userInfo':userInfo,'partners':partners};
                 resolve(retObj);
                 ...
                });                    
},
```

What I needed to do was cloning `the retObj` variable above before calling `resolve(...)`.
Please see the codes below for details.

I think, this is due to the fact that `the retObj` object has `the userInfo` variable as an `Object` type and `the partners` as an `Array` type so I should have not used `the retObj` directly.

```
model: function() { 
    return new  Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
                 ... 
                 // JSON data from the server
                 //{"userInfo":{"uid":0,"username":"","isRegistered":0,"email":""}, "partners":[{"value":0,"name":"ASM","idx":0},{"value":1,"name":....}...]} 

                 var retObj = {'userInfo':userInfo,'partners':partners};
                 var newRetObj = jQuery.extend(true, {}, retObj);
                 resolve(newRetObj);
                 ...
                });                    
},
```

Cloning the retObj using jQuery.extend() resolves the error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property:***".

Thanks again for all who've tried to help me out for this issue and Please feel free to comment more if you think there are something I missed.